# Mosquitto MQTT devices slowing down

Tags: automation, mqtt

I have a problem with 2 esp8266 , both are wired up with ds18b28 via onewire and send data with MQTT .But , if i turn them on both , just one of them transmits data , i tested them separate and no problem , here is the code.Both esp-s use the same code

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#include <PubSubClient.h>

#include <OneWire.h>

#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 5
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);

DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);


const char* ssid = "PIREV-PC_NETWORK";
const char* password = "********";
const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.0.4";

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
long lastMsg = 0;
float temp = 0;
int inPin = 5;

void setup_wifi() {
delay(10);
Serial.println();
Serial.print("Connecting to ");
Serial.println(ssid);
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
{
 delay(500);
 Serial.print(".");
}
Serial.println("");
Serial.println("WiFi connected");
Serial.println("IP address: ");
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void reconnect() {
while (!client.connected()) {
Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
if (client.connect("arduinoClient_temperature_sensor")) {
   Serial.println("connected");
} else {
   Serial.print("failed, rc=");
   Serial.print(client.state());
   Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
   delay(5000);
  }
 }
}

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(115200);
setup_wifi(); 
client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
pinMode(inPin, INPUT);
sensors.begin();
}

void loop()
{
if (!client.connected()) {
reconnect();
}
client.loop();

long now = millis();
if (now - lastMsg > 300) {
 lastMsg = now;
 sensors.setResolution(12);
 sensors.requestTemperatures();
 temp = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
 Serial.println(temp);
 if((temp > -20) && (temp <60))
   {
   client.publish("dev/test/temp2", String(temp).c_str(),TRUE);
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Are you using EXACTLY the same code or is the topic different between each device? Also are you using the same client id for both devices?

Comment: Just the topic is different , nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client id needs to be different for every client.

In this case it looks like you are using `arduinoClient_temperature_sensor` for both sensors, this won't work as the broker will always disconnect the first sensor when the second one connects (and then vice versa when that sensor tries to reconnect)

```
void reconnect() {
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // The value passed to client.connect needs to be unique
    if (client.connect("arduinoClient_temperature_sensor")) {
      Serial.println("connected");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}
```